# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at app.js

Tags: typescript

Hey guys I am exporting enume.ts file to app.ts, and after importing it in app.ts when I try to compile for example console.log(ROLE.ADMIN) it gives error Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at app.js.
I tried finding solution, changed compilerOptions module: to none from commonjs, still gives same error. I checked other stack overflow posts with same problem, gave me no solution, and I tried majority of those.
And no I did not write exports instead of export.

Comment: Post some code, and your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: @paul here I posted it down, I can post my tsconfig.json file ,its huge, I didn't change anything in it it's built with watch. Nothing is currently changed from the usual.

Comment: You're going to need to either post the `tsconfig` file and some more code.  I was able to get it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-lamarr-6zvz2

Comment: @paul , cant post more code that's it hahah. I tried the same as u wrote it, with index.ts and all, still gives me error, but only with app.js

Comment: Delete your answer.  The sample code belongs in the question section.  I made an update (pending review) which copied your sample code into the question section.

Comment: You're going to need to post you're `tsconfig` file or else I can't be of any help.  At this point, your actual code/folder structure deviates from the sample code you posted, or your `tsconfig` file is messed up.  Without knowing, I can't help.

Comment: @Paul i posted it down

Comment: Post it above in the question section.  And delete your two answers, your code doesn't belong there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207509/discussion-between-paul-and-boban-bobo-banjevic).

Answer (score 0):

You had a bunch of necessary options commented out in your `tsconfig.json` file.  Take a look at the `tsconfig.json` in the link below.  The file is a merged version of the file you posted and some default values.  I removed the comments and commented out options because it's just noise and should be removed from your project.  Take a look at the Console output in the sandbox.  You'll see the references are working.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-pond-cwx2x