# ReferenceError: exports is not defined vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I'm doing a project in Vue.js 3.2, and I had to update webpack. After a lot of headaches, I managed to get it to *almost* work, the compiler runs fine, but the browser gives me these errors:

[image: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at chinck-vendors.js:9:1]

This is my vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            fallback: {
                "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
                "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
            }
        },
        target: "node",
    }
}
```

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60139733/10047984) but i don't really know how to translate it to Vue.

If there's something else I have to share to understand the problem please tell me.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Nope. Created a new project and moved the code.